# recursive_directory_iterator bug in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, filesystems, visual-studio-2017, symlink

I was trying to use `filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` to go through all the files in a directory, recursively, and I noticed that the Visual C++ implementation follows directory symlinks regardless what directory options are provided. By default, `directory_options::none` is used, but there is no difference in the result between `none` and `follow_directory_symlink`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
   for (auto const & entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(
      "c:\\test",
      fs::directory_options::none))
   {
      if (fs::is_regular_file(entry))
         std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This program always prints the following:

```
c:\test\readme.txt
c:\test\test\doc1.txt
c:\test\test\doc2.txt
```

In this example, *C:\test* is a directory that contains a file (*readme.txt*) and a symlink to *D:\test*, that in turn has two files. With `directory_options::none`, I expect the output to list only *c:\test\readme.txt*. (BTW, the symlink was created with the command `mklink /d test d:\test`.)

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.4.4.

This looks like a bug to me, but I wonder what other implementations do. I don't have Clang or gcc to test.

Comment: In the last released version of GCC7.2, filesystem is also in the experimental directory!

Comment: I suggest bringing this up at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: I did report it https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3144662

Comment: I got the following response from the VC++ team: "The experimental filesystem implementation shipping with Visual C++ currently does not support symlinks, so behavior like this is not entirely unexpected. We will be addressing this when we implement filesystem as-standardized-in-C++17, which will be Soon^TM."